# auto adding #gsc.tab=0 after the URL

Tags: search, google-custom-search

if I open my domain , it looks like this

```
http://wwww.domain.com/#gsc.tab=0
```

I know it happen with Google custom search.
but is there a way to fix it?
may be javascript solution or something else.

it seems a lot of sites aren't fixed yet , you can take a look here

```
    http://hydroharbor.com   
    http://shwesathtagan.com      
    http://techwhack.co/google-custom-search-engine-adding-gsctab0-url-43721/
```

if someone could help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

I faced the same problem the current url was being changed with **#gsc.tab=0** 
 in the end like this

```
http://example.com#gsc.tab=0
```

**SOLUTION**

1:First make sure the Result browsing history is disabled ,see [here](https://techjourney.net/google-custom-search-engine-appends-gsc-tab0-in-url/)

2: Replace this

```
 <gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

with this

```
<gcse:search enablehistory="false"></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 4):

Advice on disabling "Results Browsing History" in the Custom Search control panel worked for me...

In the custom search control panel, select: Search Features > Advanced > Results Browsing History [disable]

Comment: Thank you Meez! I had to turn OFF "Results Sorting" to get rid of the "#gsc.tab" issue in our Wordpress install.

Comment: This option can also be set in code and overwrites the UI behavior. `<gcse:search enableHistory="false"></gcse:search>`

Answer (score 0):

The "#gsc.tab" issue has now been fixed.

[See here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/1I2OATAx3xk)

Comment: the is a very bad answer, can you explain what the fix is?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with fixed, it is October 2022 now (5,5 years later) and I still had to turn OFF "Results Sorting" to get rid of the "#gsc.tab" issue as described in the accepted answer.